# Angular pass route to lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-routing

i have a app-routing.module where at specified path i lazyload another module.

```
{
        path: 'ROUTE1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../modules/modulename/modulename.module').then((val) => val.modulename),
    },
```

this is the routing of my child module:

```
 {
        path: '',
        component: modulenameComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'register/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('../../modules/secondomodule/secondomodule.module').then((val) => val.secondomodule),
    },
```

What i want now if i go to the path: register/:id is go to the secondmodule.routing at

```
  {
        path: 'register/:id',
        component: Nomecomponent,
       
    },
```

instead of

```
  {
        path: '',
        component: OtherComponent,
       
    },
```

Is possible in lazyloading pass to the loaded module a specified path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want, your path would be

```
/register/123/register/123
```

since your route is a concatenation of all paths in hierarchy (root path + child path recursive)

Rethink your navigation.

Comment: I have a direct method to navigate to this route and it work fine. But i have an external component, only for some user, that must pass to another module and only after insterted their code, they can redirect to this module. If instead of lazy loading, i call directly component it works, i could be use these method

Comment: Anyhow, you have yourself another module or you have to include this particular module somewhere else

Comment: It works, i just concatenate path and take the ID at the end of path so the result is a link to /register/save/123.